# How to Refresh RequestDigest in SharePoint 2010 Angular SPA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, angularjs

I previously built an AngularJS application in SharePoint 2013 and that is great, now I am building a similar application in SharePoint 2010. I have two questions specific to SharePoint 2010:

1. How do I refresh the Request Digest from JavaScript?
2. How do I perform CRUD operations on a document library from JavaScript using the SP2010 REST Interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to make an asp.net page named index.aspx. Inside that page I added the FormDigest server control:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint"
  Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls"
  Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-strict-di>
<head>
  <script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
  <script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
  <script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
  <script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
  <script src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I then created an angular service that calls $interval to periodically post a soap message to '/_vti_bin/sites.asmx':

```
$interval(refreshFormDigest, 1440000);
function refreshFormDigest() {
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'text/xml',
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
      'SOAPAction': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetUpdatedFormDigest'
    }
  };
  var soapMsg = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ' +
    'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ' +
    'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
    '<soap:Body>' +
    '<GetUpdatedFormDigest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" />' +
    '</soap:Body>' +
    '</soap:Envelope>';  
  $http.post(appWebUrl + '/_vti_bin/sites.asmx', soapMsg, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    //TODO: parse the response xml here and update the hidden input value named __REQUESTDIGEST
  });

}
```

The response comes back in XML which I parse using a regular expression to get the request digest value. The whole thing works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage REST interface available in URL

```
http://siteurl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc
```

**Create**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://siteurl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listName",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Created");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Failed";
    }
});
```

**Update**

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "http://siteurl/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listName(1)", //1 is item id to update
     contentType: 'application/json',
     processData: false,
     headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
     },
     data: JSON.stringify(data),
     success: function (data) {
        alert("Created");
     },
     error: function (data) {
        failure(data);
     }
});
```

**Read**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://siteurl/_vti_bin/listdata/listName(1)",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Failed');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good start but I also need to know how to upload a file to said document library from javascript. As a bonus copying a file would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

Using my angular module SennitShareAngularJs.

For get request digest you need only writte this code:

`sennitRestApi.requestDigest`

For mor details and download see the link below

[SennitShareAngularJs github](http://github.com/buenokinder/SennitShareAngularJs)

Comment: That library appears to be for SharePoint 2013